# Startx and VNC are not working on AWS Lightsail CentOS7

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, centos7

I installed tigervnc on AWS Lightsail CentOS7. When I try to connect to the server with vnc client it shows a black screen. Then I tried to run startx, it gives an error. "xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.6301 does not exist".
Is it possible that GUI is not working on AWS Lightsail?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: startx will by default attempt to start an X session on a physical display.  You want to edit ~/.vnc/xstartup to launch a window manager or desktop session of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I was using AWS Lightsail Server with low configuration. The problem was gone after I moved to another AWS Lightsail server with high configuration. I think the problem was in low memory.